# Is there any way to use variables in css?

Tags: css

I would like to write css code like this. Is there any plugin is available for this?

```
mcolor = #ff00ff;

body
{
    color: mcolor;
}

.ele
{
    width: body.width / 2;
}
```

Comment: CSS cannot make calculations. You CAN however use percentages:`.ele { width:50%; }`. Note that this is a percentage of the parent div, not the body.

Comment: If this won't do for you there is no other option than to use a javascript implementation. The LESS or SASS, as suggested by Logan, are some sort of frameworks that use javascript to fill your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at LESS: http://lesscss.org/ or SASS: http://sass-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

In pure CSS it's impossible. But there is a [working draft of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/). It will not be available in the browsers any time soon so in the mean time use LESS or SASS as @Logan Serman suggests

Comment: Wondering why someone downvoted this answer. If there is a mistake, feel free to write a comment, but don't hide behind a downvote because you're cowardly ;) Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

No, Not have any way to use variable in css.

If you want to use varaible then you want to use css in php or javascript or orher language.

For more information. you learn this on

http://lesscss.org/

OR

http://sass-lang.com/